# can't insert the image dynamically in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to insert the image source by passing through the props but i am getting the error message

Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '../4.0 - Assets/Images/video-list-1.jpg'

how can i solve it my code for the component where i want to insert is

```
const VideoComp = (props) => {
  const {title, channel, image} = props.data;
  return(
    <div className="side-video-content">
      <div className="side-video-content-img">
        <img src={require(image)} alt=""/>
      </div>
      <div className="side-video-content-title">
        <h4>{title}</h4>
        <p>{channel}</p>
      </div>
  </div>
  );
}

export default VideoComp;
```

and i am passing from this component

```
class SideVideo extends Component {
  state = {
    sideVideo: {
      id: 1,
      title: "Become A Travel Pro In One Easy Lesson",
      channel: "Todd Welch",
      image: "../4.0 - Assets/Images/video-list-1.jpg",
    },
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="side-video-container">
        <h5>Next Video</h5>
        <VideoComp data={this.state.sideVideo}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SideVideo;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, try to define a js with all the image you need like:

```
// ../4.0 - Assets/Images/images.js
const images = {
 myimage: require("./video-list-1.jpg"),
 ...
}
export default images;
```

Then, in `SideVideo`:

```
import images from "../4.0 - Assets/Images"

 class SideVideo extends Component {
  state = {
    sideVideo: {
      id: 1,
      title: "Become A Travel Pro In One Easy Lesson",
      channel: "Todd Welch",
      image: images.myimage,
    },
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="side-video-container">
        <h5>Next Video</h5>
        <VideoComp data={this.state.sideVideo}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And in `VideoComp`:

```
const VideoComp = (props) => {
  const {title, channel, image} = props.data;
  return(
    <div className="side-video-content">
      <div className="side-video-content-img">
        <img src={image} alt=""/>
      </div>
      <div className="side-video-content-title">
        <h4>{title}</h4>
        <p>{channel}</p>
      </div>
  </div>
  );
}

export default VideoComp;
```

Comment: thanks Giovanni for the quick response i tried the code but got                                                            ./src/component/sidevideo.jsx
Module not found: Can't resolve '../4.0 - Assets/Images'

Comment: import images from '../4.0 - Assets/Images';

class SideVideo extends Component {
  state = {
    sideVideo: {
      id: 1,
      title: "Become A Travel Pro In One Easy Lesson",
      channel: "Todd Welch",
      image: images.myimage,
    },
    };

Comment: It's for sure a path problem. Folder `component` is on the same level of folder `4.0 - Assets`?

Comment: yeah thanks it was not a path problem instead of declaring as an object i declared the image  in the array so have to use the index to access it thanks buddy appreacite your help can you please refer any source where i can get some background info why i have to do this way thanks

Comment: Ciao, try to read [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6391) discussion. Basically the problem is how require works. require is loaded one time before runtime so is not possible to pass a dynamic string.